# luaotfload-tool error on Solaris Intel

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

Fully updated TexLive 2022 on Solaris x86_64 Intel which is preventing any docs compiling under lualatex:

```
$ luaotfload-tool -u
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:3521: [string "t"]:17380: malformed number near '0x1.4000000000000p+3'
```

Comment: There was [some discussion about this (also listing a workaround)](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/203) and the hope was that it will be fixed in TeX Live 2022... You could try pinging the TeX Live team again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commented suggestion, I tried this workaround works for now:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/amd64/values-xpg6.o lualatex ...
```

Which allows `luaotfload-tool` to build the cache.

Comment: Just information, for those who find this thread via search: the `LD_PRELOAD` is a system command, which is very specific to the operating system. Never use it unless you are an expert, or are relying on expert advice from those who have your system.